# How to avoid configserver.yml from appearing in Spring Cloud config server /env resource output?

Tags: spring-cloud

I was able to define a Spring Boot project and include the following dependency in my pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I then added the @EnableConfigServer annotation on my class. So far so good. I then created a bootstrap.yml file to point to my git repository. The application runs and picks up the configuration file I have defined in my repository. All seems to work well. To get to this point there was a lot of trial and error and digging around.

When I invoke http://localhost:8888/env I see two applicationConfig JSON objects appear. The first is from the configserver.yml file, which is embedded in the spring-cloud-config-server jar that contributes to the base spring context. The second is from my bootstrap.yml.

I am able to get access to the property files from my git repo as configured in my bootstrap.yml and am wondering how to override other properties that appear in the configserver.yml such as the server.port value. I apologize if this question was already asked. I am attempting to work with the spring-cloud-config-server jar as is and without modification and without pulling the code to rebuild.

Comment: You mentioned "my class" but you seem to be using the main method from the jar file (or else you specifically asked for the `configserver.yml` somewhere else). Is that right? If you wrote your own main class with `@EnableConfigServer` it won't know anything about the YAML in the jar file. This is how all the samples are written (and there are quite a few), so I don't know but it sounds like you haven't taken the shortest possible route to where you are either.

Comment: I looked at the samples and reworked the yaml files. All is ok. Now I have another issue regarding having a config client pull from my git repository through the config server. I will start another thread on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to have been with the yaml files. I created an application.yml and reworked my bootstrap.yml, taking direction from the spring cloud samples.